# Resume Formats for Sound Editors/Designers

Tags: format, standard, jobs, editing

First of all, I really enjoy this site and wish everyone tons of luck in their current and future projects.  My question is one regarding the structuring of resumes or CVs for sound editors.  Is there an industry-accepted standard for sound editing or sound designing resumes?

I've seen quite a number of resumes from sound editors over the years, but I have yet to find any kind of standardized throughline between any of them.  Some resumes are company/job title driven, others are project-based, and still others focus on education and skills.

If there isn't an industry standard, is there a resume format that has worked well/repeatedly with you guys?

OR... are resumes a thing of the past?

Comment: Hey Peter! A belated welcome to you!

Comment: Who hasn't been seen on SSD since October 25th ;)

Answer (score 3):

Writing a resume can be a door opener, not very likely but it just might.
I wouldn't worry about formal formatting unless applying for major company jobs.

In my mind, short, to the point and easy to read is what matters.

A brief description of you as a person and what you have done previously is fine.
Dont write "up" what you've done.

If you have no specific experience in the particular field, say so. 
I'd take personality, hunger for knowledge, reliability and punctuality ahead of anything else for an entry position. Even experience won't rate as hi as the others in my book...

Don't claim to be a PT wiz just because you've attended a PT 101 class.

Dress decently but not formally.

If you really want to be a musician and be in a band, don't contact me, you'll just waste my time.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Erik.  I've been working as an editor for quite a number of years, and though I have a resume, I've never really had real use for it.  I'm a staff editor at a facility, but any additional work I've gotten outside of that gig has been through word of mouth.  Thank you again for your input.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome!  My personal take on it is that they aren't used much but it's nice to have one on hand that someone can casually view for more information on their own.  The one I have made though is sorted by order of what I believe to be most important from the top down:

- Name, regional location (Los Angeles, CA for instance but not the address), phone#, IMDB link
- A few selected titles for filmography/body of work
- Affiliations & Awards (if any) (IATSE, MPSE, CAS, AMPAS, ATAS, etc)
- Work experience (as in, who have I worked for or contracted with studio/facility wise on a regular basis)
- Education

I prefer the simple approach, no statement of purpose or such of that nature.  Nothing that gloats either.  My thoughts per a recent posting on here about promotion is that by building credibility in one's body of work first, the credibility does the promotion for oneself over time.  So in that sense, I feel the resume follows suit.  Listing the straightforward no-fluff credible facts, which corroborate with IMDB/LinkedIn etc, and to-the-point.

Then again this is just one take on it, as I've always been an independent contractor and thus my body of work (IMDB) is the only true common-denominator-paper trail representing my overall work history.  Others may differ though based upon their work situation.

Comment: Steve!  Thanks for chiming in.  Your bullet points pretty much sum up the way I already had my resume structured.  Glad to see I was on the right track.  I've still got you on my radar by the way, but this summer we've been cursed with being just busy enough to not "need" any additional editors.  Translation: No budget, no time.  Let's stay in touch!

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen anybody get a gig from a resume although I'm sure it must have happened at some point.

It's been my experience that it's who you know. If you are recommended for a job they will sometimes want to see a list of what you've worked on. These days most people just use their IMDB page.

If you don't have a history to fall back on or personal recommendations good luck.
Crews are getting smaller and smaller and competition for gigs can be fierce. I've seen good, experienced people work only three months out of the year.

Good luck and never say no. You never know who you're gonna meet on some small minimum rate job and hopefully impress. They will remember you. ALWAYS be kind and respectful to ALL assistants. Sound Supervisors frequently ask their opinion. I've seen people come in for an interview, leave thinking they've got it and then the assistant say, "That person's a dick don't hire 'em." Then boom, they're crossed off the list. On the flip side I have gotten jobs because an assistant recommended me.

Answer (score -1):

Recently I was wondering to create my resume with best format. I met one of the HR, she suggested me to use word format for resume creation. Word format attracts recruiters eye while scanning it. When compared to three formats chronological resume works best.